# IMDB Web Scraping in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I am new to web scraping in python. I am using code

**Input:**
`first.find('p',{'class':''})`

**Output:**

```
    Directors:
<a href="/name/nm0751577/">Anthony Russo</a>, 
<a href="/name/nm0751648/">Joe Russo</a>
<span class="ghost">|</span> 
    Stars:
<a href="/name/nm0000375/">Robert Downey Jr.</a>, 
<a href="/name/nm0262635/">Chris Evans</a>, 
<a href="/name/nm0749263/">Mark Ruffalo</a>, 
<a href="/name/nm1165110/">Chris Hemsworth</a>
</p>
```

**Question:**
I want to separate out Directors and Stars from the above output and only need string values

Comment: This question could benefit from including a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that users can better understand how to answer your question. i.e. An example page, the process used to define `first` in your code example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this example as a start how you could parse Directors and Stars:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


txt = '''    Directors:
<a href="/name/nm0751577/">Anthony Russo</a>,
<a href="/name/nm0751648/">Joe Russo</a>
<span class="ghost">|</span>
    Stars:
<a href="/name/nm0000375/">Robert Downey Jr.</a>,
<a href="/name/nm0262635/">Chris Evans</a>,
<a href="/name/nm0749263/">Mark Ruffalo</a>,
<a href="/name/nm1165110/">Chris Hemsworth</a>
</p>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(txt, 'html.parser')

directors, stars = [], []
for a in soup.select('a'):
    prev = a.find_previous_sibling(text=lambda t: ':' in t)
    if 'Directors' in prev:
        directors.append(a.text)
    else:
        stars.append(a.text)

print('Directors:', directors)
print('Stars:', stars)
```

Prints:

```
Directors: ['Anthony Russo', 'Joe Russo']
Stars: ['Robert Downey Jr.', 'Chris Evans', 'Mark Ruffalo', 'Chris Hemsworth']
```